# Trouble making Symbolic Link

Tags: linux, system-installation, debian-installer

I have a problem with easy-creds tool

I already installed the tool but when I try to run the tool it gives me this error

```
 Couldn't find radiusd. If its installed please create a symbolic link in /usr/bin
```

[!] Some prereqs missing, functionality may be impaired. Review README file.

I do not know how to make a symbolic link and what to make it for

Answer (score 0):

As explicitely said in the error message, you need to install radiusd. Have you done it?
https://www.vultr.com/docs/install-freeradius-on-debian-7

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you DID install `radiusd`, I'll give you some background on your question.

---

PART 1: Symbolic links

A symbolic link is just a pseudo-file that actually just points elsewhere, i.e. the original file. If the original file is removed, the link points to a non-existing position and thus is broken. You can create one via:

```
 ln -s /original/file /link/position/and/name
```

Now we will have a symbolic link `name` in the directory `/link/position/and/` pointing to the original file `file` in directory `/original/`.

---

PART 2: PATH variable and executable files

Whenever you execute a command in a terminal by just typing its name, you actually are searching your `PATH` for an executable file of the same name. The `PATH` itself is a list of directories where to search for possible commands; display yours by typing `echo $PATH` and you will have a colon-separated list of directories where programs are installed:

```
$echo $PATH
/home/johnny/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

If `easy-creds` cannot find `radiusd` in `/usr/bin` despite it being installed, the executable is somewhere else and needs to be linked to `/usr/bin` (as `easy-creds` seems to search for it there)

```
ln -s /path/to/radiusd /usr/bin/radiusd
```

Will create a symbolic link `radiusd` in `/usr/bin` pointing to the actual program.

---

I hope this brief overview will give you a basic idea of how things work.

Comment: sorry i am not that good in linux how can i make it this is the files path freeradius: /usr/sbin/freeradius /usr/lib/freeradius /etc/freeradius /usr/share/freeradius /usr/share/man/man8/freeradius.8.gz

Comment: A short what is what for you:`/usr/sbin` -> binary files/executables (but might be linked to elsewhere: Could you give me the output from `ls -l /usr/sbin/freeradius`?) `/usr/lib/` -> libraries programs use, `/etc/` -> configuration files, ` `/usr/share/` -> a place for shared programs/files/libraries (e.g. all users) `/usr/share/man/` -> manual entries. There are more places where each could be, but just to give you an idea of how things are grouped.

Comment: Note that the previous comment is just a quick and very superficial overview.